# Jquery stop animate if another still running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I try to show and hide  element on hover  element. My code works, but when user mouseover and mouseout element very fast, animation run and run even mouseout it :(

```
$('.EventNameList').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#eaeaea' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        $(this).find('div#TrainingActionButtons').show("fast");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 800, "easeOutQuad");
        $(this).find('div#TrainingActionButtons').hide("fast");         
    }); 
    });
```

And HTML:

```
<tr>
 <td class="EventNameList">
     <div id="TrainingActionButtons">
     Some text 
  </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666227/jquery-issue-with-hoverintent-and-show-hide-for-div/4667207#4667207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the performance on this but you could tell all elements to stop and go to end, as opposed to only the current element.

```
$('.EventNameList').hover(
    function() {
        // stop([clearqueue], [jumpToEnd])
        $('.EventNameList').stop(true, true);
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#eaeaea' }, 200, "easeInQuad");
        $(this).find('div#TrainingActionButtons').show("fast");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 800, "easeOutQuad");
        $(this).find('div#TrainingActionButtons').hide("fast");         
    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for quick response :) I use this code $(this).find('div#TrainingActionButtons').stop(true, true);
and i works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You could try to call `stop(true,true)` - this will clear the effect queue and skip to the end of currently running animation. [Read more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)